# Joining HDF panels and pine frame for good

Tags: mdf, framing, hardboard

I'm currently building a green wall / cyclorama room, and one of its properties is that it has an infinity wall (curved walls with an X radius in all the corners).

After a lot of research I decided to go with 3mm HDF for the panels. 
My question is, considering that the joints between the panels will be filled with mud, sanded down, primed and painted, I cannot afford any kind of movement due to humidity or temperature changes (room will be controlled anyway), as they would crack the paint.

Aside from nailing the panels (I'm using Type C staples), would you also consider glueing them? And if so, wood glue or construction glue?

[image]

Comment: Never done this but as a general rule glueing greatly increases strength and stability so I can't imagine it wouldn't be advisable here, and construction adhesive seems like the right choice. BTW best of luck doing those compound curves in the rear corners!

Comment: @Graphus thanks! For the corners, using paper to trace the form and transfering it to the HDF plates will be the way to go!  :)

Answer (score 2):

Not enough rep on this site to comment, but I would agree with @Graphus - there's definitely some advantage from a stability-standpoint to having the panels battened down with some construction adhesive.  I would also suggest that to minimize any twist in the floating(ish?) framing, that you block off between the studs, creating a big "torsion box".
Best of luck!